# Iterative policy evaluation algorithm in "Reinforcement Learning" written by Sutton.

Tags: machine-learning, learning

[image: R]

I am studying the reinforcement learning using the textbook entitled "Reinforcement Learning An Introduction," written by Richard S. Sutton.

However, I got a weird point in the iterative policy evaluation algorithm, and cannot make sure whether I am wrong or the textbook is wrong. Hence, I am posting this question here to ask about this.

In the picture above, the following statement is stated in the second algorithm "Policy Evaluation."
$$\Delta \gets \max \left( \Delta , \lvert v - V(s) \rvert \right)$$

In my opinion, in order for the algorithm to terminate someday, $\max$ must be replaced with $\min$. However, all the *iterative policy evaluation* codes I've seen in github sticks to $\max$, not $min$.
I want to make sure what is correct, and if $\max$ is correct, can someone say why it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a mistake, the convergence is due to fixed point theorem.

We examine each state and record down what is the maximal update across the states.

We only terminate the procedure when the change in the previous iteration and current iteration is small enough.

Comment: Every iteration $\Delta$ must be increased. It cannot be smaller than the previous. Thus, I think that once $\Delta\ge\theta$, it will never be smaller than $\theta$. Thereby, the algorithm runs eternally. Am I wrong?

Comment: $\Delta$ will increase. But when you go back to to the repeat statement again, $\Delta$ is reset to $0$ again. The idea is we want the $V(s)$ to stabilize and we will only stop when such condition is met.

Comment: Oh my god!!!! $\Delta$ is forcibly set to zero at the beginning of every iteration!!!!. I got it, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Mr. Goh, May I ask one more thing regardless of this post? In the textbook, there exists a statement "This way of finding an optimal policy is called *policy iteration*." Note that the way in the statement refers to the algorithm iteratively runs policy evaluation and policy improvement. In this time, how can I accept that this is the "OPTIMAL policy"? From what I'm looking for, there doesn't seem to be a rigorous proof anywhere in the textbook.

Comment: perhaps [policy improvement theorem](http://incompleteideas.net/book/first/ebook/node42.html) is of interest.